Limit of a function when 'a' is not in the domain
Is this a correct statement that as x approaches to 'a' for f(x) where 'a' does not belong to the domain of f(x) then the limit at 'a' does not exist

In a limit $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, the number $a$ need not be in the domain of the function, but it does need to be a "limit point" of the domain, i.e. you need to be able to get arbitrarily close to $a$ from within the domain.
As an example, $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ exists and is $0$, but $0$ is not in the domain of that function.
Limits are all about what is happening to a function as $x$ gets close to $a$. They don't depend at all on what is happening at $a$ itself, so nobody cares whether $a$ is in the domain or not.
Now when you start talking about continuity, that's a different story. Then $a$ had better be in the domain, and the limit had better be the function value $f(a)$.
